# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 Eject SD Cards Itself?

Tags: drivers, mount, 16.04, sd-card

System: 16.04 Ubuntu on Macbook Air 2013-mid. I just went sleep, system locked screen and then logged in back again. I see Ubuntu ejected my SD memory card itself. I want to understand why because I cannot `mount` it again, although the memory card is connected still on the memory card slot. My `sudo fdisk -l` gives

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 148880495 148470856  70,8G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda3  148880496 150150031   1269536 619,9M Apple boot
/dev/sda4  150150032 236716438  86566407  41,3G Microsoft basic data
```

where you see no SD memory card in the memory card slot so the system has ejected the memory card. I want to know why. 
My `dmesg |tail`

```
[  195.737247] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[ 9167.311376] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 9167.311381] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 9167.311384] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_e
irp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 9167.311388] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/
A)
[ 9167.311391] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/
A)
[ 9167.311394] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/
A)
[ 9167.311397] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/
A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9167.311401] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/
A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9167.311403] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0
 s)
[ 9167.311406] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/
A)
[ 9167.311408] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N
/A)
[ 9168.569602] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 9168.608755] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 9168.608895] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 9168.610793] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 9168.611951] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 9168.611981] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 9168.612247] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 9168.614502] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 9168.872801] PM: suspend of devices complete after 260.707 msecs
[ 9168.896778] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 23.972 msecs
[ 9168.897071] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: suspending...
[ 9168.897523] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
[ 9168.897527] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 
(0x1001 -> 0x1)
[ 9168.897535] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
[ 9168.897538] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (
0x1 -> 0x0)
[ 9168.897542] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: control channel stopped
[ 9168.897543] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: suspend finished
[ 9168.897765] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 9168.912824] pcieport 0000:05:00.0: quirk: cutting power to thunderbolt controller...
[ 9169.216731] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 319.967 msecs
[ 9169.216987] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 9169.248700] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[ 9169.248701] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 9169.248703] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 9169.248944] Broke affinity for irq 49
[ 9169.249965] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 9169.261157] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 9169.261160] Broke affinity for irq 18
[ 9169.261164] Broke affinity for irq 44
[ 9169.261169] Broke affinity for irq 46
[ 9169.261176] Broke affinity for irq 49
[ 9169.262196] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 9169.273238] Broke affinity for irq 8
[ 9169.273243] Broke affinity for irq 9
[ 9169.273249] Broke affinity for irq 16
[ 9169.273254] Broke affinity for irq 18
[ 9169.273261] Broke affinity for irq 44
[ 9169.273265] Broke affinity for irq 45
[ 9169.273269] Broke affinity for irq 46
[ 9169.273273] Broke affinity for irq 47
[ 9169.273278] Broke affinity for irq 48
[ 9169.273282] Broke affinity for irq 49
[ 9169.273287] Broke affinity for irq 52
[ 9169.274327] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 9169.288023] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 9169.288123] ACPI : EC: EC started
[ 9169.288125] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 9169.288625] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 9169.308198] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 9169.308200] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 9169.323072]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 9169.324543] CPU1 is up
[ 9169.344257] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[ 9169.359064]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 9169.457164] CPU2 is up
[ 9169.682487] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[ 9169.705427]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 9169.731482] CPU3 is up
[ 9169.735565] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 9169.808280] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 9169.809372] pcieport 0000:06:05.0: quirk: waiting for thunderbolt to reestablish PCI 
tunnels...
[ 9169.824203] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1 -> 0x1001)
[ 9169.824208] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resetting switch at 0
[ 9169.825461] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0: resuming switch
[ 9169.831329] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resume finished
[ 9169.831474] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 23.386 msecs
[ 9169.837834] PM: early resume of devices complete after 6.336 msecs
[ 9169.839809] pciehp 0000:06:03.0:pcie24: Timeout on hotplug command 0x1038 (issued 9168940 msec ago)
[ 9169.843785] pciehp 0000:06:04.0:pcie24: Timeout on hotplug command 0x1038 (issued 9168944 msec ago)
[ 9169.843792] pciehp 0000:06:06.0:pcie24: Timeout on hotplug command 0x1038 (issued 9168944 msec ago)
[ 9169.843793] pciehp 0000:06:05.0:pcie24: Timeout on hotplug command 0x1038 (issued 9168944 msec ago)
[ 9169.843825] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 9169.855845] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 9169.925398] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resetting error on 0:b.
[ 9169.925443] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:b: hotplug: scanning
[ 9169.925444] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:b: hotplug: no switch found
[ 9169.925502] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: resetting error on 0:c.
[ 9169.925543] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:c: hotplug: scanning
[ 9169.925544] thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: 0:c: hotplug: no switch found
[ 9170.183835] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 9170.184154] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
[ 9170.184605] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
[ 9170.184730] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 9172.325160] PM: resume of devices complete after 2487.452 msecs
[ 9172.325509] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 9172.325511] Restarting tasks ... 
[ 9172.325640] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 9172.342832] done.
[ 9172.391750] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 9172.391755] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 9172.391757] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 9172.391759] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.391762] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.391763] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.391765] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.391767] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9172.391769] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9172.391771] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.391772] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9172.754567] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

where you seething things like

- `Broke affinity for irq`. What is this?
- ...

I do not understand how internal SD card readers work. Probably, through USB 1-2 drivers? I could not find their specific drivers

### Settings

I disabled all greedy-power saving settings that were proposed in the official manual because I think they increased the incidence of the interruptions in reading memory cards.

**Goal**: I would like to know how you investigate what causes interruptions in reading memory cards. I only see lossed connections in `dmesg`.

In `powertop` > `tunables`, I have active (`good`)

- NMI watchdog should be turned off
- VM writeback timeout
- Bluetooth device interface status
- Autosuspend for USB device Bluetooth USB Host Controller [Apple Inc.]
- Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb1]
- Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb2]
- Autosuspend for USB device BRCM20702 Hub [Apple Inc.]
- Wake-on-lan status for device wlan0
- Using 'ondemand' cpufreq governor

Output of `sudo lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 011b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 011b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 011b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
    Memory at b0a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Apple MacBookAir6,2 / MacBookPro11,1
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at b0a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:15.0 DMA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Low Power Sub-System DMA (rev 04) (prog-if 02 [EISA DMA])
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at b0a29000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at b0a28000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SPI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at b0a21000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Memory at b0a20000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at b0a2a100 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at b0a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: fast devsel
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b0800000-b09fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-000000009fffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b0400000-b06fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=9b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: b0b00000-bcbfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000bcc00000-00000000c8bfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b0700000-b07fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at b0a2a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]

02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at b0900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-ff-ff-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] #15
    Kernel driver in use: bdc-pci

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 0117
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at b0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number b8-e8-00-ff-ff-00-00-01
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] #15
    Kernel driver in use: wl

04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Apple PCIe SSD (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at b0700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Expansion ROM at b0710000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=6b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b0b00000-b8bfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000bcc00000-00000000c4bfffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Upstream Port, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: b0b00000-b0bfffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=08, subordinate=38, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: b0c00000-b4bfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000bcc00000-00000000c0bfffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 3
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=39, subordinate=69, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b4c00000-b8bfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0c00000-00000000c4bfffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=6a, subordinate=6a, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=6b, subordinate=6b, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge 4C 2012] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Physical Slot: 1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
    Memory at b0b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at b0b40000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-00-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=01c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
```

General settings by following the guide [here][1]

1. Power management. Keep defaults, not those greedy power-saving settings in the guideline. I experience a series of lost connections to my memory card, which I do not want. So no `99macbookair6` because it does not work as described.
2. Backlight. Broken links in the manual in `wget http://miek.nl/downloads/2013/mba6xbl-dkms_0.0.1_all.deb`.
3. I already did `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` in `sudo gedit /etc/default/avahi-daemon` to avoid conflicts with avahi service on LAN. Not related but can complicate.

---

Why does Ubuntu 16.04 eject itself SD cards after screen lock/night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a filesystem problem. See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288963/16920) and check the problems by `sudo fsck.vfat /dev/...` if your SD card is FAT32.